# Real Admob adds are not showing on my Android Application

Tags: android-studio, admob

I am new to AdMob and I am using banner add in my android application. test adds were working perfectly but now real adds are not showing. Now I received an Email from AdMob that

> Thank you for your interest in AdMob. After reviewing your application, our specialists have found that it does not meet our program criteria. Therefore, we are unable to accept you into our program.

But I am not violating any of there policy. Why is this happening and what is a solution now?

Comment: For what is worth, Ad companies can reject or invalidate your ApiKey if they detect that your app is not what they consider ok (which is a new low), or if you accidentally (or intentionally) abuse their API KEY/TOken to show ads all the time (Which would, technically, count as more "impressions"). So talk  the AdMob people :)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini i want to clarify that is there any policy like that after 500 or 1000 add request, the add will be shown?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know. I don't work for AdMob.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, it's about AdMob's internal guidelines.